# How do I grab the current page URL and place it into a new URL reference in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, salesforce

Here's what I'm using as a custom button control in Salesforce that executes JavaScript.

```
    location.replace('/email/author/emailauthor.jsp?retURL=/{!Case.Id}&p3_lkid={!Case.Id}&rtype=003&p7=GetURLHere&p2_lkid={!Case.ContactId}&template_id=00Xc0000000HrOk');
```

The `GetURLHere` part is where I'd like to grab the current URL and place it on the next page.

This form works like `Select Listview > Click Button > New page loads with the previous pages URL in the p7 field.`

`p7`represents a field I'd like to put it into upon page load.

The usual `document.location.href`doesn't want to work in this control.

Any idea on how to do this in the Force.com environment?

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to use the $CurrentPage object to get the current pages url as a formula expression.

```
document.location.href = '{!$CurrentPage.URL}';
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. The page that has the button is different from the page that loads when you click the button. When you click the button, the page the button was on should be in a field on the new page.